# How can I extract a string (or text) from a SELECT query returned from a plpgsql function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I may be contorting postgres here, but fundamentally, what I would like to do is take a string variable and pass it to an sql command (in this case COPY) using only psql.

So this is what I came up with. The commands are separated into 2 files because I want to be able to use the mydb_functions in other situations:

file one: mydb_functions--1.0.sql (in share/extension and with mydb_functions.control also setup as described in the manual. Given a filename, returns a full filepath. this is done solely to make the COPY statements in add_data.sql below, neater.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fpn(filename text) RETURNS TEXT as '
  DECLARE 
    mypath text := ''/path/to/my/directory/'';
  BEGIN
    RETURN mypath || filename;
  END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

file two: add_data.sql . This exists solely to copy data into existing postgres tables using psql at the command line. Note: running psql with superuser privileges is required because of the CREATE EXTENSION command.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS mydb_functions;
-- haven't figured out how to create a function without arguments yet.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (dummyvar text) RETURNS text as '     
  DECLARE 
    filepath RECORD;
  BEGIN 
    SELECT * INTO filepath from fpn(''mydatafile.data'');
    COPY tablename (columnname) FROM filepath;
  END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The part I am stuck on is how to extract a text from the filepath record to use in the COPY command. Any tips on an easier way to achieve this are also welcome. I think creating a table to store the variable is far easier than this. But I would like to finish the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is running `COPY` with a dynamic target path, use `EXECUTE` to run a `format`ted SQL query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test () RETURNS text as $$ 
  DECLARE 
    filepath RECORD;
  BEGIN 
    SELECT * INTO filepath from fpn('mydatafile.data');
    EXECUTE format('COPY tablename (columnname) FROM %L', filepath);
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See, this fails:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    somevar text;
BEGIN
    somevar := '/tmp/somepath.csv';
    COPY tablename(columnname) FROM somevar;
END;
$$;
```

but this works:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    somevar text;
BEGIN
    somevar := '/tmp/somepath.csv';
    EXECUTE format('COPY tablename(columnname) FROM %L', somevar);
END;
$$;
```

See:

- [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html)
- [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)

`format()`'s `%L` specifier auto-quotes literals. `%I` does the same for identifiers.

---

If as I originally thought, you're talking about getting data into `psql` from outside, you may find `psql` variables and variable interpolation useful:

```
$ psql -v filepath=/path/to/my/directory/mydatafile.data regress
regress=> SELECT :'filepath';
               ?column?                
---------------------------------------
 /path/to/my/directory/mydatafile.data
(1 row)
```

Note that the colon is unquoted, then the variable name is quoted. Odd syntax, I know. This only works in `psql`; it won't work in (say) PgAdmin-III.

Alternately, you can use a here-document (unix-like shell specific, won't work in Windows' `cmd.exe`) to do quoted text interpolation:

```
$ FILEPATH=/path/to/my/directory/mydatafile.data
$ psql regress <<__END__
SELECT '$FILEPATH';
__END__

               ?column?                
---------------------------------------
 /path/to/my/directory/mydatafile.data
(1 row)
```

Both of these show how to insert a variable from the shell level into `psql`. From there, it's a matter of using it in your function. Like this, say, with `-v filename=myfilename.csv`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS text as $$
  DECLARE 
    filepath RECORD;
  BEGIN 
    SELECT * INTO filepath from fpn(:'filename');
    COPY tablename (columnname) FROM filepath;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or just this with `-v filepath=/full/path/to/myfilename.csv`:

```
$ psql -v filepath=/path/to/my/directory/mydatafile.data regress
regress=> COPY tablename (columnname) FROM :'filepath';
```

Comment: thankyou for your detailed response. I appreciate the extra time you spent showing how the psql variables can be used inside of pl functions.